# How to convert integer to decimal format in Java (Android Studio)?

Tags: java

I am trying to convert my two answers text1 and text2 into a decimal format. How is this possible?

```
int number1, number2, answer, answer2;
EditText edit1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.aNum);
EditText edit2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.bNum);
TextView text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answerNum);
TextView text2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answerNum2);
number1 = Integer.parseInt(edit1.getText().toString());
number2 = Integer.parseInt(edit2.getText().toString());
answer = (number2 / (number1 * 1000)) * 60;
answer2 = answer/60;
text1.setText(Integer.toString(answer));
text2.setText(Integer.toString(answer2));
```

Comment: Yeah, exactly the same way you did : `Float.parseFloat`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by decimal format?

Comment: I tried that, but I get the error "Incompatible types. Required: int Found: float"

Comment: Try harder, you should be able to debug such a simple compile error. If not, then Android programming is too complicated for you right now

Answer (score 1):

The first issue is the ints are whole numbers, i.e. no decimal places so if you had:

```
int a = 3;
int b = 2;
int result = a / b;
```

The result would be 1 not 1.5. If you need to preserve the floating point values cast them to doubles or floats instead. Then you can then use String.format to display the value correctly:

```
text1.setText(String.format("%.2f",answer));
```

Which will display the answer to two decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html):

i.e.:

```
new BigDecimal(theInputString);
```

Comment: Why using `BigDecimal` here ? He never mentionned the possibility of overflowing...

Answer (score 0):

Use float variable type instead of int, and Float class instead of Integer class:

```
float number1, number2, answer, answer2
EditText edit1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.aNum);
EditText edit2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.bNum);
TextView text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answerNum);
TextView text2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answerNum2);
number1 = Float.parseFloat(edit1.getText().toString());
number2 = Float.parseFloat(edit1.getText().toString());
answer = (number2 / (number1 * 1000)) * 60;
answer2 = answer / 60;
text1.setText(Float.toString(answer));
text2.setText(Float.toString(answer2));
```